# Magento 1.x addFieldToFilter using AND instead of OR (how can I join search using AND)

Tags: database, magento-1, collection, sql

I am trying to use AND and OR based on user input.

OR = success

But I an unable to setup AND queries for addFieldToFilter

**question**: how can I add the second (looped filter) using AND to join

```
$search_array = array();
$or_array = array();
if (is_numeric($query)) {
    // this becomes OR and is great
    $search_array[] = array('attribute' => 'entity_id', 'eq' => $query);
    $search_array[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like'=>'%'.$query.'%');
} else {

    if (strpos($query, ' ') !== false) {
        $morewords = explode(" ", $query);
        foreach ($morewords as $word) {
            // This needs to be AND clause - need help
            $search_array[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like'=>'%'.$word.'%');
        }
    } else {
            $search_array[] = array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like'=>'%'.$query.'%');
    }
}

    $collection->addFieldToFilter($search_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for `AND` condition

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
...) {
...
$this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
$this->_customer = $customers;
...
}

public function execute() {
...
        $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter("email", array("eq" => "test1@mailinator.com"))
                ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq' => 1));
        echo (string)$collection->getSelect();
        exit;
...
}
```

the expected query result is `SELECT`e`.* FROM`customer_entity`AS`e`WHERE (`e`.`email`= 'test1@mailinator.com') AND (`e`.`store_id`= 1)`

Comment: Can I add the filter call in a foreach loop??

Comment: if you want to put filter query into foreach then put like **$collection->addFieldToFilter("email", array("eq" => "test1@mailinator.com"));** in foreach. not your ways, in your ways your are like merging all filter into one it means it will run like **OR** condition not **AND**

Comment: Got fatal error every time when looping. Unknown attribute. Which is strange because it is right there. In the end used where condition for and and orwhere condition to add or condition in sql